# How to debug problems with Wayland on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, gnome, wayland

I have recently performed massive cleaning of my Fedora 32 system, which included high amount of packages being removed from the system, by the way removing desktop environment I was using. Before, I was using Deepin DE(desktop environment form Deepin OS, backported to Fedora), but I decided to switch back to Fedora-default Gnome. The only problem, I'm experiencing now, is that Gnome uses X11 instead of Wayland, which it has to use by default. I have a suspicion, that while cleaning my system, I might have accidentally deleted some sort of package required for Gnome to work with Wayland. I tried googling some information about managing Wayland. According to information I found, I tried:

1. Setting /etc/gdm/custom.conf var 'WaylandEnable' to true

```
WaylandEnable=true
```

2. Setting /etc/gdm/custom.conf var WaylandEnable to false and commenting it

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

By the way, in GDM sessions list, I do not have Gnome on Xorg variant. I have only Gnome and Gnome Classic variants.
I'm not really good at understanding how to professionally manage graphical subsystems like Xorg or Wayland, on Linux, so I don't know, where to search.

Please help me find out, what I'm missing to make gnome to use wayland or where to see if gnome fallbacks from Wayland to X11(if it so)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if installing or re-installing `gnome-session` might be helpful.

Comment: No. It didn't helped. Reinstalled both gnome-session-wayland and gnome-session-xsession. But thanks for a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem(it was kinda obvious)
I was using a proprietary Nvidia driver, which, currently, does not have any support of Wayland. That's why, system used to fallback to X11

Solution for me, it's to use a Nouveau driver, which in my case(and it's a pity) has some problems with my GeForce MX150